# How do you code a password reset functionality when the email and password is in a different database table?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a password reset functionality but I am having trouble to make it work probably because the password and email is in a different table.

How can I make it work?

Comment: a join? but really its a wild guess based on the question details

Comment: `different table` not complex rather **`different DATABASE`.** Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER`. When Email will be updated, the corresponding password will be updated.

Or you can use `TRANSACTION` as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use join on the tables when the specific email is called by update function the corespending record in other table will also have affect of update.